# Is it possible to make an object available everywhere in a program in java?

Tags: java, object

If I have two objects, in and out, is it possible to make those objects static or available every where? So that no matter where I am in a program I can type

```
out.println("Hello!");
```

and it functions without having to pass in and out into different objects like so?

```
happyCat(BufferedReader in, PrintStream out);
```

Please let me know if this is possible.

```
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(server.getInputStream()));
PrintStream out = new PrintStream(server.getOutputStream());
```

Comment: Possible? Yes. Good design? Absolutely not.

Comment: @Keppil Can you elaborate? Wouldn't having to pass the BufferedReader around be a poor design? Sending it from one object to the next over and over? Instead of creating it once and using it permanently?

Comment: Global variables are almost always a bad idea. Maybe you could encapsulate reading input and printing output in one (or two) dedicated classes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a class Streams and use static :

```
class Streams {
   // I don't know where "server" come from
   public static BufferedReader in = ...
   public static PrintStream out = ...

}
```

an then use :

```
 Streams.in and Streams.out
```

Comment: Public static class variables are effectively global variables in every program that imports the class. So yes, this is the answer. The only difference between this and the OP's attempt is the use of the class prefix on the names (which is a *good thing*).

Answer (score 1):

You can change the default in and out streams of the Java environment by calling `System.setIn()` and `System.setOut()`, see [javadoc for class System here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#setIn%28java.io.InputStream%29). When any piece of code references the default streams, they will be "redirected" to your instances.

```
System.setOut(myOutput);
System.setIn(myInput);
...
System.out.println("hello"); // This will print to your output stream
System.in.read();             // This will read from your input stream
```

Answer (score 0):

No.  In every source file, you will either have to [statically import](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/static-import.html) your `in` and `out`:

```
import static pkg.MyGlobals.in;
import static pkg.MyGlobals.out;
```

or you will have to qualify uses as in

```
pkg.MyGlobals.out.method(...)
```

There is no way to define new packages like `java.lang` which are implicitly imported, and there are no classes whose static members are implicitly imported.

Only the methods defined on `Object` are available unqualified everywhere and that is only because they are inherited in every context that can contain code that could reference them.

---

[Section 6.5.6.1 Simple Expression Names](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.5.6.1) explains how simple names like `in` and `out` are matched to fields of objects:

> If an expression name consists of a single Identifier, then there must be exactly one declaration denoting either a local variable, parameter, or field visible (§6.4.1) at the point at which the Identifier occurs. Otherwise, a compile-time error occurs.

Following links from that starting point should convince you that there are no hidden mechanisms for this.